# Auth.net Hosted Accept: User authentication failed due to invalid authentication values

Tags: authorize.net

I created an Accept hosted integartion. This integration works fine in sandbox mode, but fails in LIVE mode with the following error:

> User authentication failed due to invalid authentication values.

I verified that my transactionKey and api_login_id are correct and that I am using the correct URL.
The settings on the auth.net account are set to LIVE.

What else could be the issue? I see banter about requiring a signature key also, but nothing in the docs.

Below is the code for the request:

```
<getHostedPaymentPageRequest xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">
<merchantAuthentication>
        <name>{hidden api_login_id}</name>
        <transactionKey>{hidden transaction key}</transactionKey>
</merchantAuthentication>
<transactionRequest>
        <transactionType>authCaptureTransaction</transactionType>
        <amount>7.94</amount>
<order>
<invoiceNumber>138437174</invoiceNumber>
</order>
        <billTo>
         <firstName>First</firstName>
         <lastName>Last</lastName>
         <company>Company</company>
         <address>Address</address>
         <city>City</city>
         <state>ST</state>
         <zip>11111</zip>
         <country>US</country>
      </billTo>
      <shipTo>
         <firstName>First</firstName>
         <lastName>Last</lastName>
         <company>Company</company>
         <address>Address</address>
         <city>City</city>
         <state>ST</state>
         <zip>11111</zip>
         <country>US</country>
      </shipTo>

</transactionRequest>
<hostedPaymentSettings>
        <setting>
                <settingName>hostedPaymentBillingAddressOptions</settingName>
                <settingValue>{"show": true, "required":true}</settingValue>
        </setting>
        <setting>
                <settingName>hostedPaymentButtonOptions</settingName>
                <settingValue>{"text": "Pay"}</settingValue>
        </setting>
        <setting>
                <settingName>hostedPaymentReturnOptions</settingName>
                <settingValue>{"showReceipt" : false, "url":"https://www.hiddendomain.com/plugins/authnet_iframe_communicator.html","urlText":"Continue","cancelUrl":"https://www.hiddendomain.com/plugins/authnet_response.php?action=cancel","cancelUrlText":"Cancel"}</settingValue>
        </setting>
        <setting>
         <settingName>hostedPaymentShippingAddressOptions</settingName>
         <settingValue>{"show": false, "required":false}</settingValue>
</setting>
        <setting>
                <settingName>hostedPaymentStyleOptions</settingName>
                <settingValue>{"bgColor":"#B00"}</settingValue>
        </setting>
        <setting>
                <settingName>hostedPaymentIFrameCommunicatorUrl</settingName>
                <settingValue>{"url": "https://www.hiddendomain.com/plugins/authnet_iframe_communicator.html"}</settingValue>
        </setting>
</hostedPaymentSettings>
</getHostedPaymentPageRequest>
```

Comment: Double check everything as you clearly do not have your setup configured correctly. Make sure you are pointing to the production URL with the production credentials *everywhere*. If you still get an error, write a simple script that just tries to login  to Authnet. If you get an error then your credentials are incorrect.

Comment: @JohnConde ty for your response. I just ran an authentication request as per https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/#authentication using the production url https://api.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api and the same transaction key and api login - it was a SUCCESS <resultCode>Ok</resultCode><message><code>I00001</code><text>Successful.</text></message>. This verifies the creds are correct. Are there any other settings in auth.net that could prohibit the hosted accept form transaction from completing successfully?

Comment: @JohnConde - also note that the accept hosted form comes up ok, it's only upon entering credit card info and submitting the form that we get the error. If the creds were incorrect, we wouldn't even get the hosted form in the first place, right?

Comment: I don't use the hosted form so I am unsure how far you will get before it errors out.

Comment: I just verified that the hosted form will error our with bad creds by altering my trans key. The form wouldn't even show, displaying "Missing or invalid token." instead.